# Cmd prompt executes code without py prepended but ignores command line arguments (Automate the Boring Stuff)

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt

Running Python 3.9 in Windows 10. Python installed via Windows 10 Store.
PATH environment has directory with file being executed.

I'm running the following code from Chapter 12 of Automate the Boring Stuff, a google map launcher:

```
#! python3
# mapIt.py - Launches a map in the browser using an address from the
# command line or clipboard.

import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    # Get address from command line.
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    # Get address from clipboard.
    address = pyperclip.paste()

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
```

When I open CMD and type:

```
mapIt.py Empire State Building
```

The program will execute except ignore the `Empire State Building` arguments from CMD and use whatever is on my clipboard instead when launching google maps on the browser. Prepending py here gives me `[Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Through troubleshooting I have found that when I navigate to the folder in CMD and try the code it still ignores the command line arguments, however, when I navigate to this folder and prepend py the code will work as intended. So this:

```
C:\(file_directory)>py mapIt.py Empire State Building
```

will launch google maps with Empire State Building in the search.

Can anyone illuminate what is going on here? I do have Mu installed and was wondering if that version of Python included in that installation is messing with which python is being called in command prompt.

Comment: Can't reproduce. What's happening when you try `python3 mapIt.py Empire State Building`?

Comment: @scenox I get `python3: can't open file 'C:\Users\My_name\mapIt.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

If this helps, mapIt.py is in a different directory: my desktop.

Comment: Then switch to Deskop directory before execution with `cd Desktop` or use `python3 C:\Users\My_name\Deskop\mapIt.py Empire State Building`

Comment: I found the issue and posted my solution. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

Something went wrong with my file associations when installing multiple versions of Python.

To fix the problem, I went to my python script, right clicked it, selected "Always open using this app.", and navigated to `C:\Windows\py.exe`.

Now when I open CMD and only type `mapIt Empire State Building`, the program launches my browser to google maps with a search for Empire State Building.

I suspect this is a registry issue but as far as I am concerned it is now working.